# Save file uploaded to server as binary string from javascript to file using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using js File API and reading file with FileReader like this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = handleReaderLoad;
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

and this is reader load handler in which I get file content and send it to server using jquery.ajax call:

```
function handleReaderLoad(evt) {
        fileToSend.Content = evt.target.result;

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ file: fileToSend }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
```

on server side I have:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Upload(UploadedFile file)
        {
            // save file
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\" + file.Name, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                bw.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Content));
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            return null;
        }
```

and the UploadedFile is:

```
public class UploadedFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

I managed to save file, but content is different. I know that it has something to do with encoding but I just don't get same file on server. Can you please tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in what format you want to save the file  and what format it is in right now ...

Comment: This likely because JSON is a textual format.. not binary. Youll have to serialize it..

Comment: BTW you are swallowing the exception...

Comment: I want to save it in same format it was on client side, so any format, doc, image format, pdf...

Answer (score 0):

you can read all the content from the uploaded file and then save all the content.
for Example :-

```
 Stream fileStream = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileStream);
 string str=sr.ReadToEnd();
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);// your FileStream :-
 sw.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution could be (which i am also using). Rather than using JSON and AJAX combination. You can write HTTPHandler to upload file and can call it using Ajax same way you have done in your code.

It will allow you to upload any kind of file and with minimum code change [Example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sateesh-arveti/archive/2010/11/19/ajax-file-upload-using-jquery.aspx)